# Sending requests via Google Indexing API (Python)

Tags: performance, python-3.x, google-api

I've started learning Python several months ago. This code uses Google API to send URLs to Googlebot.

I appreciate it if someone can review my code, and advice better practices in classes/method structure, sending requests and logging responses.

How to start the program ([link GiHub](https://github.com/drkwng/google-indexing-api))

```
import json
import re

import httplib2
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


class GoogleIndexationAPI:
    def __init__(self, key_file, urls_list):
        """
        :param  key_file: .json key Google API filename
        :param urls_list: .txt urls list filename
        """
        self.key_file = key_file
        self.urls_list = urls_list

    def parse_json_key(self):
        """
        Hello msg. Parses and validates JSON
        """
        with open(self.key_file, 'r') as f:
            key_data = json.load(f)
            try:
                input(f'Please add OWNER rights in GSC resource to: {key_data["client_email"]} \nand press Enter')

            except Exception as e:
                print(e, type(e))
                exit()

    @staticmethod
    def get_domain():
        """
        Input URL and strips it to a domain name
        :return stripped_domain:
        """
        domain = input('Enter domain you are going to work with: ')
        stripped_domain = re.sub('(https://)|(http://)|(www.)|/(.*)', '', domain)
        return stripped_domain

    @staticmethod
    def choose_method():
        """
        Choosing a method for Google Indexing API request
        :return method: method name
        """
        while True:
            choose_msg = input('Choose one of methods (print number) and press Enter \n'
                               '1 - URL_UPDATED\n'
                               '2 - URL_DELETED:\n')
            if '1' in choose_msg:
                method = 'URL_UPDATED'
                break
            elif '2' in choose_msg:
                method = 'URL_DELETED'
                break
            else:
                print('Please enter correct number')

        print('You chose method: ', method)
        return method

    def get_urls(self):
        """
        Gets URL list from a file and clean from not unique and not valid data
        :return final_urls:
        """
        urls = []
        domain = self.get_domain()
        try:
            with open(self.urls_list, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                for line in f:
                    urls.append(line.strip())

                # Clean not unique urs
                urls = list(set(urls))
                # Delete urls without ^http or which don't contain our domain name
                for url in urls.copy():
                    if ('http' not in url) or (domain not in url):
                        urls.pop(urls.index(url))

                # 200 requests a day quota :(
                if len(urls) > 200:
                    print(f'You have a 200 request per day quota. You are trying to index {len(urls)}. ')

                    len_answer = input(f'I will make requests only for the first 200 urls containing {domain}. '
                                       f'Continue (YES/NO) ???\n')
                    if 'yes' in len_answer.lower():
                        final_urls = urls[0:199]
                        left_urls = urls[200:]

                        # Write urls over quota limit in file
                        with open('not_send_urls.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as log:
                            for item in left_urls:
                                log.write(f'{item}\n')
                        print(f'There are {len(left_urls)} not send to Googlebot. \n'
                              f'Check not_send_urls.txt file in the script folder')

                    elif 'no' in len_answer.lower():
                        exit()
                    else:
                        print('Please enter correct answer (YES / NO)')
                else:
                    final_urls = urls

                if len(final_urls) < 1:
                    assert print('There are no urls in your file')
                    exit()

                return final_urls

        except Exception as e:
            print(e, type(e))
            exit()

    def single_request_index(self, __url, __method):
        """
        Makes a request to Google Indexing API with a selected method
        :param __url:
        :param __method:
        :return content:
        """
        api_scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing"]
        api_endpoint = "https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish"
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(self.key_file, scopes=api_scopes)

        try:
            http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
            r_content = """{""" + f"'url': '{__url}', 'type': '{__method}'" + """}"""
            response, content = http.request(api_endpoint, method="POST", body=r_content)
            return content

        except Exception as e:
            print(e, type(e))

    def indexation_worker(self):
        """
        Run this method after class instance creating.
        Gets an URL list, parses JSON key file, chooses API method,
        then sends a request for an each URL and logs responses.
        """
        self.parse_json_key()
        urls = self.get_urls()
        method = self.choose_method()
        with open('logs.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for url in urls:
                result = self.single_request_index(url, method)
                f.write(f'{result}\n')

        print(f'Done! We\'ve sent {len(urls)} URLs to Googlebot.\n'
              f'You can check responses in logs.txt')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    g_index = GoogleIndexationAPI('cred.json', 'urls.txt')
    g_index.indexation_worker()
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. The title should be a brief introduction into what the code does rather than your concerns about the code. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add PEP484 type hints, such as `get_domain() -> str`
- The exception handling here:

```
            try:
                input(f'Please add OWNER rights in GSC resource to: {key_data["client_email"]} \nand press Enter')

            except Exception as e:
                print(e, type(e))
                exit()
```

is a little odd. Do you expect for the exception to come from the fact that `client_email` is missing as a key? If so, it's best to check for that directly rather than rely on an exception. Even if you were to rely on the exception, you should narrow the caught type. Finally: this `input` doesn't look to belong in this method, and is an interaction that should appear in an area of the code dedicated to user interface.

- Your regular expression

```
     '(https://)|(http://)|(www.)|/(.*)'
```

doesn't look strict enough; you should probably match on `^http` to make sure you're looking at the beginning of the string. However, I think the `sub()` is at odds with what you're asking the user. You're asking for the *domain* and not a URL, so why bother stripping off the protocol? I'd just let it fail at the network level if they give you something that isn't a domain. Better yet, rather than attempting to be clever and strip off substrings, just loop-validate that it's a valid domain by passing it to `socket.gethostbyname`.

Along the same lines,

```
            urls = list(set(urls))
            # Delete urls without ^http or which don't contain our domain name
            for url in urls.copy():
                if ('http' not in url) or (domain not in url):
                    urls.pop(urls.index(url))
```

doesn't *actually* check for `^http` as you've commented, so either you need to use a regex, or use `startswith`. Consider running the urls through `urllib.parse.urlparse` and verifying that the scheme is either `http` or `https`, and that the netloc is equal to the given domain.

Also, this block can be replaced with

```py
url = [u for u in set(urls)
       if u.startswith('http') and domain in u]
```

Consider representing the return value of `choose_method` as an enum rather than an unconstrained string.

What's this? `"""{"""` You don't need a triple-quoted string for one brace. Is `r_content` supposed to be JSON? If so, you need to replace your single quotes with double quotes. You should also enclose this literal string in double quotes:

```
    print(f'Done! We\'ve sent {len(urls)} URLs to Googlebot.\n'
          f'You can check responses in logs.txt')
```

so that you don't have to escape your apostrophes.